# Passing a segment of an already open FileStream to a Stream parameter

Tags: c#, file-upload, openstack

I'm working on a method to upload large files to an OpenStack provider. OpenStack typically has a limit of 5GB per file, but this can be worked around by uploading said file in segments and then adding a manifest.

According to http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_large_objects.html this happens as follows:

```
# First, upload the segments
curl -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'         http://<storage_url>/container/myobject/00000001 --data-binary '1'
curl -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'         http://<storage_url>/container/myobject/00000002 --data-binary '2'
curl -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'         http://<storage_url>/container/myobject/00000003 --data-binary '3'

# Next, create the manifest file
curl -X PUT -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'         -H 'X-Object-Manifest: container/myobject/'         http://<storage_url>/container/myobject --data-binary ''

# And now we can download the segments as a single object
curl -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'         http://<storage_url>/container/myobject
```

I'm trying to create the first part in C# but I want to prevent opening / closing / re-opening the FileStream. This presents a problem becausing I'm using (and would like to keep using) HttpClient.PutAsync for the actual uploading of the file. For a file that doesn't need segmented upload, that looks like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "SomeToken");

    using (var fs = File.Open(localFilePathAbs, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var bs = new System.IO.BufferedStream(fs, 17000000))
    {
        var response = client.PutAsync(url, new StreamContent(bs), cancellationToken).Result;
        return new XauthResponse<string> { Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result), StatusCode = response.StatusCode };
    }
}
```

So in order to get this working, I need to pass a stream to `HttpClient.PutAsync` that continues reading an already-opened stream up to a maximum amount.

The code I have is:

```
private static void PutSegmented(string url, string localFilePathAbs, long segmentSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (url == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    if (localFilePathAbs ==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("localFilePathAbs");
    if (segmentSize == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("segmentSize");

    var fileSize = new FileInfo(localFilePathAbs).Length;

    // The number of parts we'll have to upload
    var parts = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Ceiling(((double)fileSize) / segmentSize));

    // Open the file to upload, use a BufferedStream of roughly 16 megabytes
    using (var fs = File.Open(localFilePathAbs, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var bs = new System.IO.BufferedStream(fs, 17000000))
    {
        for (var partIndex = 1; partIndex <= parts; partIndex++)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            // Todo: partIndex has to be prepended with one or more zeros to ensure correct sorting when downloading the object
            var segmentUrl = url + "/" + partIndex;

            using (var fsSub = new SomeStreamCopyClass(inputStream: bs, maximumToRead: segmentSize))
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "SomeToken");

                var response = client.PutAsync(segmentUrl, new StreamContent(fsSub), cancellationToken).Result;
                // Todo: Use response for verification
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO: Upload the manifest
}
```

So if I could replace the line `using (var fsSub = new SomeStreamCopyClass(inputStream: bs, maximumToRead: segmentSize))` with something that actually exists, I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public class PartialFileStream : FileStream {
    public PartialFileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, long firstChunkLength)
        : base(path, mode, access, share) {
        Advance(firstChunkLength);
    }

    public long ReadTillPosition { get; private set; }

    private long _length;
    public override long Length => _length;

    public void Advance(long nextChunkLength) {
        this.ReadTillPosition += nextChunkLength;
        if (ReadTillPosition > base.Length) {
            // if we are outside the stream, adjust
            var diff = ReadTillPosition - base.Length;
            nextChunkLength -= diff;
            ReadTillPosition = base.Length;
            if (nextChunkLength < 0)
                nextChunkLength = 0;
        }
        _length = nextChunkLength;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count) {
        if (base.Position >= this.ReadTillPosition)
            return 0;

        if (base.Position + count > this.ReadTillPosition)
            count = (int) (this.ReadTillPosition - base.Position);


        return base.Read(array, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Basically we inherit from `FileStream` and in `Read` method read only till specified `ReadTillPosition`. When you upload next chunk - advance `ReadTillPosition` by the length of the next chunk.

Comment: When I use this, the line `client.PutAsync(segmentUrl, new StreamContent(bs), cancellationToken).Result` throws an Exception with a bunch of InnerExceptions: `An error occurred while sending the request` -> `The request was aborted: The request was canceled.` -> `Cannot close stream until all bytes are written` - maybe `PutAsync` closes the stream within `StreamContent(bs)` - any ideas?

Comment: That error means it uses Stream.Length to set Content-Length http header, then it tries to write data to the _body_ stream, and it discovers that it read less data than Stream.Length. Solution would be to override Stream.Length too, and set it to the length of your current chunk (see my updated answer).

Comment: It throws an `ObjectDisposed` exception at `if (ReadTillPosition > base.Length)` within the `Advance` method. I really think `PutAsync` disposes the `StreamContent` which in turn disposes the underlying stream. So I don't think this is going to work with inheritance, unless there's a way to prevent the disposal. +1 for your effort though, this might work in different scenarios

Comment: Tried to use simple HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient? There you have full control of how you write stream to body, so won't need to guess how authors of HttpClient implemented that. With that this solution should work (actually I used it several times already with HttpWebRequest).